# front panel audio jack not working

Tags: sound

I have a problem with my front panel audio jack. It is not working after I plug in my headphones. The rear jack is working fine with the speakers.

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu after expiry of Windows XP Pro and learning to use a totally new O/S which I am not very familiar with.

I checked for answers for configuration on the front panel audio jack that is to add the line in `alsa-base.conf` file with this:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

I did and `alsa force-reload` and `reboot` but there is still no sound from my front panel audio jack. I know it is working since I had dual boot with Windows XP prior to this and it worked fine in windows with no problem. Can someone help me? my audio system is realtek HD audio build-in with VIA chipset. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem after updating my system from ubuntu 14.04 to ubuntu 16.04. In the end I changed my BIOS and it fixed the problem. There I find my front panel was using 'HD' card and I changed it to 'AC97'. After rebooting the sound comes out.

Comment: This worked for me as well.